# In BigQuery, group by where date is <= each unique date in table column

Tags: google-bigquery

We have the example data `t1` and we are trying to create the final output from the query below, where there is 1 row per unique date in the data

```
with
  t1 as (
    select '2022-12-01' as gameDate, 3 as stat1, 7 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-01' as gameDate, 2 as stat1, 5 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-01' as gameDate, 5 as stat1, 6 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-02' as gameDate, 3 as stat1, 8 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-02' as gameDate, 4 as stat1, 7 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-02' as gameDate, 2 as stat1, 8 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-02' as gameDate, 3 as stat1, 8 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-03' as gameDate, 1 as stat1, 6 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-03' as gameDate, 2 as stat1, 6 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-03' as gameDate, 3 as stat1, 8 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-03' as gameDate, 4 as stat1, 9 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-03' as gameDate, 4 as stat1, 5 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-04' as gameDate, 2 as stat1, 9 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-04' as gameDate, 1 as stat1, 7 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-04' as gameDate, 2 as stat1, 7 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-04' as gameDate, 1 as stat1, 5 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-04' as gameDate, 4 as stat1, 9 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-05' as gameDate, 3 as stat1, 8 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-05' as gameDate, 3 as stat1, 6 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-05' as gameDate, 4 as stat1, 6 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-06' as gameDate, 1 as stat1, 5 as stat2 union all
    select '2022-12-06' as gameDate, 3 as stat1, 7 as stat2
  ),

  data_stacked as (
    select '2022-12-01' as rowDate, * from t1 where gameDate <= '2022-12-01' union all 
    select '2022-12-02' as rowDate, * from t1 where gameDate <= '2022-12-02' union all 
    select '2022-12-03' as rowDate, * from t1 where gameDate <= '2022-12-03' union all 
    select '2022-12-04' as rowDate, * from t1 where gameDate <= '2022-12-04' union all 
    select '2022-12-05' as rowDate, * from t1 where gameDate <= '2022-12-05' union all 
    select '2022-12-06' as rowDate, * from t1 where gameDate <= '2022-12-06' 
  )

select
  rowDate,
  count(*) as ct,
  sum(stat1) as sumStat1,
  sum(stat2) as sumStat2
from data_stacked
group by 1 order by 1 asc
```

We are looking to group by `<= each date`, and within groupby to compute the num rows and sum of stat1, stat2 within group. The example above technically works, although it does so by hardcoding dates, and so is not scalable, not a great long term solution.

Is there a bigquery solution here that can find the distinct `gameDate`s from `t1` and use those gameDate's to do this groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select
  gameDate,
  sum(count(*)) over(order by gameDate) as ct,
  sum(sum(stat1)) over(order by gameDate) as sumStat1,
  sum(sum(stat2)) over(order by gameDate) as sumStat2
from t1
group by 1 order by 1 asc
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: wow I did not think a solution would be this straightforward. This is incredible!

Comment: Do you know if there are docs that cover the particular *"sum with an over(order by), inside a sum"* technique

Comment: unfortunately no. recently, i saw some article on that topic but i have not have chance to read it, so it is purely based on title. maybe someone reading this post will point to it :o)

Comment: we are looking to modify this to sum over a rolling `3-date` basis, rather than over all of the dates. Is this possible? In this case, the last row for `gameDate = 2022-12-06` would then have `ct = 10`, and `sumStat1` and `sumStat2` summing over the 10 rows where gameDate is 12-04, 12-05 and 12-06.

Comment: it looks like adding `ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` after `order by gameDate` in the `over()` clause is doing the trick? Does this sound right?

Comment: if there is no gaps in days - it should work. otherwise you should consider using `RANGE` vs. `ROWS`

Comment: we will give RANGE a look. Simply replace ROWS with RANGE in the query?

Comment: not really, you need also make sure that order by part is int (I think) - read documentation. If still problem - search here on SO for `RANGE` - there should be plenty of examples including my answers